# Which dimensionality reduction technique works well for BERT sentence embeddings?

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction, natural-language, language-models, embeddings

I'm trying to cluster hundreds of text documents so that each each cluster represents a distinct topic. Instead of using topic modeling (which I know I could do too), I want to follow a two-step approach:

Create document embeddings with Sentence-BERT (using SentenceTransformer)
Feed the embeddings into a cluster algorithm
I know I could e.g. use k-means for step 2, but I prefer a soft cluster algorithm as my documents sometimes belong to multiple topics. So I want to get a probability for each response to belong to each cluster. My embeddings have 768 dimensions and when implementing a soft cluster algorithm (Gaussian Mixture Models), I realized that the high dimensionality caused problems. So I was thinking about using a dimensionality reduction technique (e.g., PCA) and feed the factors into the cluster algorithm.

However, I'm not very familiar with dimensionality reduction in such high-dimensional space and especially not in the context of NLP. Can anyone advice on a good approach / method here?

Thank you!

Comment: You can try to look into the paper here: https://aclanthology.org/W19-4328/. They also have the github code published.

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV. Please add a reference for your link in case it dies in the future. Thx

Comment: Doi of the above: 10.18653/v1/W19-4328    doi's are unlikely to die soon.